# How to handle multiple services in ServiceStack?

Tags: c#, servicestack

All the examples, have an `EntryService` of some kind that gets registered in the `AppHost`

```cs
public AppHost() : base("Test HttpListener", typeof (EntryService).Assembly)
{
}
```

But my app needs to have many services. As just a simple example, I also need RESTful endpoints for `Customers`, `Products`, `Orders`. I would create a folder called Services and add a new class into each one like the following:

```cs
public class CustomersService : Service
```

and

```cs
public class ProductsService : Service
```

Is the `EntryService` just the single entry point to get everything started and then you can have many services on top of that, or is the intent to have just ONE service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `typeof(EntryService).Assembly` is an Assembly, which tells ServiceStack to register and wire-up all services in that dll. The AppHost constructor allows you to split services across multiple assemblies.

You can also register services manually see the wiki on [Modulrazing services](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Modularizing-services) for more info.

Comment: That makes sense.  My confusion was in this example http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/ where HelloService is the name of the first service you create, but really that is just saying grab the assembly that that service exists in, doesn't matter which one and it will grab all of them for that assembly.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: `public MyAppHost()
            : base("MyService", new[] { typeof(MyFirstService).Assembly, typeof(MySecondService).Assembly})`

If your app contains more than 1 assembly with services.